# SwiftUI's Canvas won't appear in Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swiftui, preview, objective-c-swift-bridge

I'm trying to use SwiftUI in my Objective-C project, so I use this following step: 
[this article](https://medium.com/@iainbarclay/adding-swiftui-to-objective-c-apps-63abc3b26c33)

after that, I'm success bridging this 2 files to my Objective-C project. but in my file SwiftUIFile.swift, my canvas cannot be resume. when I try to resume, nothing happened.

[image]

here's the code

```
import SwiftUI

@available (iOS 13.0, *)
struct DetailInterfacesUISwift: View {

    var labelName = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text(labelName)
    }
}

@available (iOS 13.0, *)
struct DetailInterfacesUISwift_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailInterfacesUISwift()
    }
}
```

**note**
 1. I already delete script in build phases, nothing happen
 2. I already clean project and delete core simulator downloaded
 3. And still not working.

Comment: It is something project specific. I've created Storyboard-based Objective-C iOS 12.0 min-spec project, then added Swift class to create bridge, then added SwiftUI view & added available wrapper, and Preview just works. Tested with Xcode 11.2.

Comment: What is your os version ?

Comment: @Asperi my base project was iOS 11.0 but i tried change to iOS 12.0 . but doesn't work at all

Comment: @KishoreKumar macOS Catalina 10.15.1, project from 11.0 changed to 12.0

Comment: @Axel please keep iOS version 13 because swiftUI is only supported from iOS - 13

Comment: @kisalready change to iOS version 13.0f, still no canvas in xcode. but if i create new project swfitUI, the canvas appeared. why is this happen?